# Using the cut command in UNIX to get the last period

Tags: unix, command, cut

Lets say I have lots of ip numbers (2 ip numbers per line separated by a space) to look through (here are two lines):

```
67.21.89.48.1623 139.91.131.115.110
211.47.82.64 139.91.134.123.445
```

One of them might not have a port so the number of periods are never consistent. I only want the ip number of the first one (without the port) and only the port of the second set (without the ip number). So it should look something like:

```
67.21.89.48 110
211.47.82.64 445
```

Or it could look like this:

```
67.21.89.48.110
211.47.82.64.445
```

It doesn't really matter as long as I know where the IP and port are located.

I've been using something like this:

```
cut -d'.' -f1-4,9 < file.txt
```

But that only works with a consistent amount of periods. Any way to cut from the back instead?

Comment: Not as standard, no.  You need to use a different tool to do the job, I think.  Your choices are legion, and include `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`, and probably a whole lot more.

Comment: Is the second address guaranteed to have a port number?

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the IP address/port number? Putting a colon between the IP address and the port number (rather than separating adress and port using a period) would be much easier to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jonathan points out in the comment, using `cut` would be very complicated because the numbers of the columns you need may differ.

Here's an example in `sed`:

```
$ echo "67.21.89.48.1623 139.91.131.115.110
211.47.82.64 139.91.134.123.445" | sed -r 's/^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(.*)\.([0-9]{1,4})$/\1 \4/'
67.21.89.48 110
211.47.82.64 445
```

You can run it as:

```
sed -r 's/^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(.*)\.([0-9]{1,4})$/\1 \4/' logfile.txt
```

`[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` is probably a lame regex for an IP address, but it was the first that I could think of. You can replace it with something smarter.
Maybe you don't even need to check what's between the dots, just take everything before the 4th period and after the last one.

Answer (score 3):

Verbose format:

```
perl -n -e 'print "$1 $2\n" if m/^
                                 ((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)      # IPv4 address
                                 (?:\.\d+)?             # Optional port
                                 \s+                    # White space
                                 (?:(?:\d+\.){4})       # IPv4 address plus dot
                                 (\d+)                  # Port number
                                 \s*$                   # Optional white space
                                /x' perl.data
```

One-liner:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 $2\n" if m/^((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)(?:\.\d+)? (?:(?:\d+\.){4})(\d+)\s*$/'
```

This only prints anything if the second entry has a port number; if it doesn't, the line is skipped.

The IP address and port number recognition can be made symmetric if you prefer (even though the second IP address won't be printed):

```
perl -n -e 'print "$1 $4\n" if m/^ \s*                  # Optional white space
                                 ((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)      # IPv4 address
                                 (?:\.(\d+)) ?          # Optional Port number
                                 \s+                    # White space
                                 ((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)      # IPv4 address
                                 (?:\.(\d+))            # Mandatory Port number
                                 \s* $                  # Optional white space
                                /x' perl.data
```

I've used `\d+` for 'one or more digits'; for IPv4 dotted decimal address components, that could be made into `\d{1,3}` for 'one to three digits', and the port number could be `\d{1,5}` for 'one to five digits'.

If you're really detail oriented, you can even limit the number ranges more precisely, but that probably isn't worth it.  This is a common feature of regex handling; you work up something that is good enough for the job at hand — without necessarily handling every possible variation that the malicious might throw at you.  You have to make a judgement call on what to do.